# Python class attributes missing

Tags: python

I am making a game in python. I ran into some issues with the code. I defined my mobs as different classes, making it easy to edit later on. The issues I ran into is that I cannot call upon the health to deal damage on it.

````
class spaceStalker(object):
  def __init__(self, name, hp):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = hp
mobList = [spaceStalker]
mob = random.choice(mobList)
killList = ["not killed the beast!", "killed the beast!"]
kill = random.choice(killList)
def game():
  if mob == spaceStalker:
    fleeAtt = input("A Space Stalker has appeared! Attack or flee? ")
    if fleeAtt == "Attack":
      hitPass = input("Attack or Pass? ")
      if hitPass == "Attack":
        spaceStalker.hp -= 50
        print(spaceStalker.hp)
  else:
    print("1")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an instance of the class

```
mobList = [SpaceStalker('some name', 54)]
```

And when you do the type of mob checking, you can do it with `isinstance(object, classname)` :

so instead of:

```
if mob == spaceStalker:
  #dosomething
```

use:

```
if isinstance(mob, SpaceStalker):
  #dosomething
```

I also suggest you to use getters and setters for your class:

```
class SpaceStalker(object):
  def __init__(self, name, hp):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = hp

  @property
  def hp(self):
    return self.__hp

  @hp.setter
  def hp(self, hp):
    #some validation here
    self.__hp = hp
```

Also, maybe you want to use the classname convention (camelcase) so I've written it as `SpaceStalker`

Comment: Just a quick question. How can I remove health from the mob?

Comment: `mob.hp = mob.hp - 50`